# Python3, iterate to JSON array without name

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm trying to iterate through this json array :

```
[{
    "date": "2018-02-21T12:53:00",
    "name": "System date",
    "ID_BBData": "none",
    "TOKEN_BBData": "none",
    "rawValue": 540916682
},
{
    "date": "2018-02-21T12:53:00",
    "name": "Temperature sensor 1",
    "ID_BBData": "none",
    "TOKEN_BBData": "none",
    "rawValue": 11
},
{
    "date": "2018-02-21T12:53:00",
    "name": "Value week",
    "ID_BBData": "none",
    "TOKEN_BBData": "none",
    "rawValue": 1810
}]
```

With this loop :

```
# print the keys and values
for key in jsonObject:
    value = jsonObject[key]
    print("The key and value are ({}) = ({})".format(key, value))
```

Where jsonObject is the json above.
The problem is that the json is enclosed by [] but there isn't any name to this array.

Any clue to iterate through this one ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The name of "the `[]` JSON" *is* `jsonObject`, no? It's a *list*. Iterating over a list yields the individual list items, not the keys.

Comment: If you want a clue : there's no such thing as a "json object" in Python. json is a text format, once parsed it yields the equivalent Python data types : `lists` for json arrays, `dicts` for json objects, etc. So what you have here is a Python `list` of Python `dicts`. Now you can learn how to iterate over a Python `list` and how to use a Python `dict` (both being required skills if you hope to do anything with Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should understand that your object is a list of dictionaries. You can check this easily, if you put the data into a variable, say lst, and then check the types:

```
>>> lst
[{'date': '2018-02-21T12:53:00', 'name': 'Temperature sensor 1', 'ID_BBData': 'none', 'TOKEN_BBData': 'none', 'rawValue': 11}, {'date': '2018-02-21T12:53:00', 'name': 'Value week', 'ID_BBData': 'none', 'TOKEN_BBData': 'none', 'rawValue': 1810}]
>>> type(lst)  # the type of the whole datastructure
<class 'list'>

>>> type(lst[0])  # the type of the first element of the list
<class 'dict'>
```

If you understand, that you have such a structure, you can begin to think about looping through the items of the list, of which each is a dictionary:

```
>>> for lst_item in lst:
...     for key, value in lst_item.items():  # this is python3 specific
...         print('key: {} value: {}'.format(key, value))
... 
key: date value: 2018-02-21T12:53:00
key: name value: Temperature sensor 1
key: ID_BBData value: none
key: TOKEN_BBData value: none
key: rawValue value: 11
key: date value: 2018-02-21T12:53:00
key: name value: Value week
key: ID_BBData value: none
key: TOKEN_BBData value: none
key: rawValue value: 1810
```

If you want to iterate a dictionary in python2, use

```
for key, value in lst_item.iteritems():
```

instead.

Comment: You can/could use `items` in Python 2 as well; it just returned a concrete list rather than an iterator. It's `iteritems` that was renamed `items` in Python 3, and getting a list requires an explicit call to `list` like `list(lst_item.items())`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over all list elements (as mentioned in comments, it's a list not a json object):

```
for line in jsonObject:
    for key, value in line.items():
        print("The key and value are ({}) = ({})".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the JSON array, then loop over it to get values as dictionaries.

```py
data = json.loads(array)
    
for event in data:
    ...
```